# How to string format SQL IN clause with Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I am trying to create a statement as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE provider IN ('provider1', 'provider2', ...)
```

However, I'm having some trouble with the string formatting of it from the Django API. Here's what I have so far:

```
profile = request.user.get_profile()
providers = profile.provider.values_list('provider', flat=True) # [u'provider1', u'provider2']
providers = tuple[str(item) for item in providers] # ('provider1', 'provider2')

SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE provider IN %s"
args = (providers,)
cursor.execute(sql,args)

DatabaseError
(1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

Comment: Curious. Why are you doing a raw sql `IN` query when you already have the django ORM?

Comment: @jdi It's a long sql query that I'm building with string concatenation based on some user-inputted values (about 20 lines long).

Comment: The ORM has aggregations though. But I guess I just have to take your word for it that the ORM can't do it :-)

Comment: I'm with @jdi here - is the table you're querying inside the ORM? (slight edit: I'm not *with* jdi, I mean that in the sense of a somewhat confused view...)

Comment: @JonClements: Jon, I am offended. We talked about being honest in public. David, we are together, and we also share similar opinions on database ORMs

Comment: @jdi LMAO - I'll fluff your pillow exactly how you like it and make you some warm milk to make-up? ;) (I think I should get +1 for least constructive comment on SO ever!) - the wife could be an issue though... :)

Comment: 3 years later and I still get surprised of what you can find when looking for some ORM advice. I'm surprised SO didn't flag this as out of topic. +1 for making me laugh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQLdb has a method to help with this:

**Doc**

> string_literal(...)
>       string_literal(obj) -- converts object obj into a SQL string literal.
>       This means, any special SQL characters are escaped, and it is enclosed
>       within single quotes. In other words, it performs:
>
> ```
> "'%s'" % escape_string(str(obj))
>
> Use connection.string_literal(obj), if you use it at all.
> _mysql.string_literal(obj) cannot handle character sets.
> ```

**Usage**

```
# connection:  <_mysql.connection open to 'localhost' at 1008b2420>

str_value = connection.string_literal(tuple(provider))
# '(\'provider1\', \'provider2\')'

SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE provider IN %s"
args = (str_value,)
cursor.execute(sql,args)
```

Comment: thats pretty cool.  Did not know about the string_literal method.  I am assuming that since MySQLdb follows the db api pretty strictly, this exists in most implementations?(sqlite3, postgres, etc)  Definetly going back to the docs

Comment: @Justin.Wood: To be honest, I didn't really know about it either, but I don't have much previous experience using MySQLdb and passing tuple values. Its always an ORM. I just looked at the docs too for this one :-)

Comment: Neat.  I work in some legacy code base that doesnt use an ORM, and we get this kinda stuff constantly.  So this is going to be a big plus for me.  You got a link to this in the docs?  Couldnt find it.  Though it is easy enough to find in the source.

Comment: @Justin.Wood: Strangely in some versions its simply called `literal`: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.connections.Connection-class.html#literal

Comment: Nah, that is an internal function for MySQLdb.  You are supposed to use the syntax you used in the answer.  It's in the source Luke!
`
        def _get_string_literal():
            def string_literal(obj, dummy=None):
                return db.string_literal(obj)
            return string_literal

        def _get_unicode_literal():
            def unicode_literal(u, dummy=None):
                return db.literal(u.encode(unicode_literal.charset))
            return unicode_literal
`

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that I don't like particularly, but will work for your apparent use-case:

```
providers = tuple[str(item) for item in providers] # ('provider1', 'provider2')
# rest of stuff...

SQL = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE provider IN {}'.format(repr(providers))
cursor.execute(SQL)
```

Comment: Could also write '`...{!r}.format(providers)` I guess - just depends on taste

Comment: This option is not good because if there is only 1i item in the list there will be a comma at the end which is invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do the string replacement before passing it to the cursor object to execute:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE provider IN (%s)" % \
        (','.join(str(x) for x in providers))
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: This may be problematic because the strings are not quoted. Maybe replace `str` with `repr` ?

Comment: could also add quotes to the join eg. `%('"'+'","'.join(str(x) for x in providers)+'"')` - that could be seen as a bit hack though I suppose

Comment: But I think its required for this solution.

Comment: FWIW, this method is susceptible to SQL injection attacks.  The accepted answer (by jdi) is safer.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have string input for ID's required:

```
some_vals = '1 3 5 76 5 4 2 5 7 8'.split() # convert to suitable type if required
SomeModel.objects.filter(provider__in=some_vals)
```

Comment: Yea I asked about this in the main comments. OP said there is a specific reason they are going for a raw query

Comment: @jdi Interesting - if the object is inside the ORM, the SQL query can be retrieved from this answer. Otherwise, I can only think they're querying something outside the ORM.

Comment: I am totally with you on that, for sure. We can only assume the OP has needs that the ORM simply can't meet.

Answer (score -1):

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE provider IN ({0},{1},{2})".format(*args) #where args is list or tuple of arguments.
```

Comment: This is a little bit limited since it assumes the length of the list, right?

Answer (score -2):

try this.... should work.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE provider IN %s"%(providers)
exec 'cursor.execute("%s")'%(SQL)
```