# How to handle user comments in a database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, cgi

I was planning to store user comments in a database and was wondering how to store the raw text that users will provide since it could contain anything. What is a common/good practice in regards to this? Do I need to parse the text or is there a special storage type that I should be using? It seemed like a lot of overhead to be parsing user comments that could potentially be quite long and I don't want to be tampering with the intended meaning of a message etc. It seemed strange to be treating a comment/forum post in the same manor as say a username/password and sanitize.

I am using `sqlite3` and some scripts to query the db and was planning on implementing something along the lines of:

```
page_id    post_number    username    content
-------    -----------    --------    -------
1          1              user_23     blah there's blah "quote" blah;':".,-=.
```

But, of course, if I was to just expand my `content` param into my `INSERT` query, there is going to be all kinds of problems with `' "` etc.

How should I be handling the `content` in this table; should it even be in the table like this? What data type should I be using etc.

Comment: once data's in the db, it's "safe". it's the mechanics of insertion/update, and what you do upon retrieval that matters.

Comment: @MarcB: So, it is normal to be handling posts/comments? I am used to going to pains over username/password, but haven't handled this before. I was half expecting someone to say "you fool, you're supposed to do x". For example, when I posted my question just then, did SO parse my question, escape characters, and insert it into a table as text/blob?

Comment: basically, yeah. I don't know what kind of processing they do in the back-end, but that's basically it. yank content of comment/answer box out, escape the text (maybe do some html validation/cleanup) then stuff it into a table.

Comment: Note that you also need to worry about [XSS vulnerabilies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). They have nothing to do with the database, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type to use depends on the overall size of the input.
Text would be my first choice.

for more on sqlite3 datatypes see
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

I would recommend you
Sanitize the input, only allow necessary markup.
Encode the content so it's safe to insert into the database.

If security is a serious concern this processing should be done server side. It won't hurt to put some of this processing load to javascript this will reduce the work done at the server. Tho it would still catch user(s) trying to circumvent the feature.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid SQL injection attacks, to make formatting of query strings easier, and to make handling of blob data possible, all databases support [parameters](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects).

In Python, it would look like this:

```
id = 1
text = "blah ..."
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(id, content) VALUES(?, ?)", (id, text))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into python, but doesn't your DB driver take care of it already? Otherwise, you have to replace escape those characters manually.

Take a look at this thread:
[How to string format SQL IN clause with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195993/how-to-string-format-sql-in-clause-with-python)