# Trouble with IN statment in SQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have code in python:

```
base = db.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='pass', db='employee')
cursor = base.cursor()
name_query = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE `employeeID` IN %s LIMIT %s"
cursor.execute(name_query, ([9006,123],1))
```

It's good work with more than one value in list,but if only one value is in the list, error is raised. Is there any way to handle this

Comment: you can go with the conditions right!!!!!!!!!....if you have one value go with one query else go with another query

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195993/how-to-string-format-sql-in-clause-with-python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood completly the problem. But I think you can use like this when there is only one value:

```
cursor.execute(name_query, ([9006,],1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to having the extra 'comma' like so:

```
select * from table where f1 in ('a',) limit 1; or
select * from table where f1 in ('a','b',) limit 1;
```

If I remove the last comma in either scenario (regardless of limit value) it works...at least in mysql.